# FastCGI and memory exhaustion error from WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, fpm

My WordPress site is currently having multiple issues. For error number 1, I tried to increase the memory limit to 6GigaBytes but the errors still occurs. Any help would be appreciated.

`[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 18648:tid 10874] [client 1xx.1xx.1xx.2xx:50xx4] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268987456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5557364296 bytes) in /var/www/html/domain.ca/wp-includes/load.php on line 1512'`

AND

`[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 28534:tid 20008] [client 1xx.1xx.1xx.1xx:5xx85] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header, referer: https://domain.ca/ [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 28534:tid 20008] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 1xx.1xx.1xx.1xx:5xx85] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : , referer: https://domain.ca/`

Answer (score 0):

You could always upgrade your server resources.

1. Try disabling FastCGI and switch to using PHP-FPM
2. Disable all plugins and themes and re-activate one at a time
3. Increase memory in `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

4. Increase memory in `php.ini`

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```